# I've sent mobilePush Message, and it seem to be sent successfully but I could not recieve message

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

[image]

In the Activity Log it sent successfully, but I couldn't recieved message.

To find out the reason, what do I need to check first?

Comment: Thank you for the checkmark. What was the problem? A comment on the answer would also be nice to let people know what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is the device registered?
2. Is the device opted-in?
3. Is the device in the audience list?
4. Was the send successful?
5. What did the feedback service say?
6. Do you see the message being received `in the device logs`?
7. Have you tried the troubleshooting steps outlined in the documentation?

Step through those things and you will find your mistake.